# PowerShell report what functions are loaded from a script

Tags: powershell, function, alias, dot-source

I have a number of scripts downloaded from the internet, and they only contain function definitions, i.e. not constructed as Modules. Hence, if I run these scripts, there is no output. If I dotsource these scripts, there is still no output, but the functions in the scripts are loaded into the session.

Is there a way that I could perform a dotsource on a script and at the same time report back visually what was loaded from that script? e.g., something like this:

```
Function "<name>" was loaded from .\script1.ps1
Function "<name>" was loaded from .\script1.ps1
Alias "<name>" was loaded from .\script1.ps1
...
```

Then, I could load a bunch of scripts, visually see what was loaded, and then be able to interrogate each function or alias with `Get-Help` if I needed more information (if they have `.SYNOPSIS` and other parameters defined within them for that purpose, that is)